# Any system can be modeled using first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Most systems can be modeled using first order system just like a temperature control system of an incubator. 

**Question 1:** How can we know that a certain system can be modeled using first order differential equation?

$$a_1\frac{dy}{dt} + a_0y = F(t)\tag{1}$$

A first order differential equation in Equation (1) may be written as:

$$\tau\frac{dy}{dt}+y = kF(t)\tag{2}$$

**Question 2:** If a step input

$$F(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t$ < 0} \\
A, & \text{if $t$ > 0}
\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

of the system has an output response of a

$$y(t) = kA( 1− e^\frac{−t}{τ}) \tag{4}$$

then the system can be modeled as first differential equation where

$$y_{max} = kA\tag{5}$$

Is this correct?

Given a step input and the graph of the step response of the system. Am i correct if I say that if the output of the system behaves similar to equation (4), then I can model the system using first differential equation?

Answer (score 0):

Your output response $y(t) = k A (1-e^{-t/\tau})$ for $t > 0$ satisfies the first-order differential equation $y' =  -y/tau  + (k/\tau) F(t)$.

Comment: wait i will edit my question.